# How do I collect all elements of a tuple?

Tags: rust, tuples

Given a tuple:
`let t = (1, 2, 3);`

How can I collect all values of `t` into, say a `Vec<u8>`, without explicitly referencing each item (e.g. `t.0`)?

It seems I cannot iterate or collect them the way I was expecting.

I was expecting something like this to work:
`let v: Vec<u8> = t.collect();`

I want to be able to easily extract all values from any tuple, such that if I have a tuple of `n` elements (of the same type), I can use the same method to get all of them into an iterable.

Comment: You cannot, as tuples can have different element types. Use an array instead.

Comment: There's probably a crate out there which allows iterating homogenous tuples though. Just as there are crates which allow collecting *into* tuples (e.g. [`Itertools::collect_tuple`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.collect_tuple).